# Android strings.xml can't escape double quote

Tags: android, xml, string

I have a String in strings.xml that should be displayed below a password field showing which characters cannot be used.

The String is:

```
<string name="password_invalid">The key can only consist of 8 to 63 ASCII characters or 64 hexdecimal digits bestehen und cannot contain these characters: \" , : ; \\ &amp; % + ' &lt; &gt; ?</string>
```

But everytime I run the code, I get an error message from Android Studio:

```
Error:(495) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in The key can only consist of 8 to 63 ASCII characters or 64 hexdecimal digits bestehen und cannot contain these characters: \" , : ; \\ & % + ' < > ?)
```

I just don't understand it why Android Studio sees the double quote as an error, I've already preceded it with a backslash as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) says I should.
What I did:

- retype the whole phrase, not just copy it from somewhere -> same error
- write the double quote with `&quot;` instead of \" -> doesn't show up
- clean/rebuild app -> same errors

I either get the error message from above or the double quote gets ignored completely. Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: I access it from a `RecyclerView` adapter to set it as text for `TextView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says that the problem is the **Apostrophe** that is this **'**, not this **"**. Try escaping the apostrophe with backslash **\'**.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! :) Looking at it too long and as English is not my native tongue made me totally miss that. I didn't consider the apostrophe itself, because it still showed up in the UI, only the double quote was missing, strange, but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The Error is not with the quote `"` but with the apostrophe `'`. So escape it with `\'` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio string resources, you can use \"" to show a single character double quote string. Optionally, you can include <![CDATA[\""...]] if you have any other special characters.